# How to save items with AsyncStorage in one screen and then display it in a different screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-native, asyncstorage

First screen is made to show the history of the saved items from the second screen.

Second screen is a QR CODE Scanner. Once the QR CODE has been scanned it shows a Modal with the information it got from the QR CODE. It also has a Button to save the information. The information that is saved is retrieved in the first screen to a FlatList.

The problem I got is that the information that is saved doesn't show up in the first screen.
I only get this in the console.log `[Error: [AsyncStorage] Passing null/undefined as value is not supported. If you want to remove value, Use .remove method instead. Passed value: undefined Passed key: @QR`

EDIT: I forgot to write that the AsyncStorage Key is exported on the top of the file so it can be imported in the FIRST SCREEN.

CODE: SECOND SCREEN WHERE I SAVE THE INFORMATION.

```
const [Link, setLink] = useState([]);

const onSuccess = e => {
    setModalVisible(true);
    console.log(e);
    const QRSave = setLink(e);
    storeQRCode(QRSave);
  };

const storeQRCode = QRSave => {
    const stringifiedQR = JSON.stringify(QRSave);

    AsyncStorage.setItem(asyncStorage, stringifiedQR).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  };

<Button
   title="Save QR"
   onPress={() => {
   scanner.reactivate();
   storeQRCode();
   showToast();
 }}
/>
```

CODE: FIRST SCREEN WHERE THE HISTORY IS SHOWN OF THE SAVED INFORMATION.

```
const [Data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    restoreQRCode();
  }, []);

  const restoreQRCode = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(asyncStorage)
      .then(stringifiedQR => {
        const parsedQR = JSON.parse(stringifiedQR);
        console.log(stringifiedQR);
        if (!parsedQR || typeof parsedQR !== 'object') return;

        setData(parsedQR);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

<FlatList
  data={Data}
  keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
  renderItem={renderItem}
 />
```

Comment: did you using react-navigation v5?

Comment: @NaldDev Yes i'm using React Navigation V5. If this option above isn't possible to do. I have to pass the saved information via React Navigation. Kinda want to avoid that since its only possible to send data via React Navigation when you only going to that specific screen??????

Answer (score 0):

I have alternative solution without passing the saved information to previous screen

there is focus listener navigation event, the code is like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    // do something when this screen back to focus for example you can load data again whenever that screen focus...

    console.log('Screen X is focus again')
    loadData()
  })

  return unsubscribe
}, [navigation])
```

You can read more about this navigation events in this [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/)

Comment: Hmm dunno really what to do with this. I have not used react navigation events before. When I have time I can look into this.

Comment: I got this going and it's showing the saved item. I ran into one problem, and that is. It's only showing one item. If i save another item. It replaces the currently saved item and doesn't add the second item to the list.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a context provider surrounding both screens, then you've got access to the data in both.

Something like:

```
//QrCodeContext.js
export const QrCodeContext = createContext();

const KEY = "QR";
export const QrCodeProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [qrCode, setQrCode] = useState({});

    //This effect hook runs on mount and loads your QR code, if it exists.
    useEffect(() => {
        const loadQrCode = async () => {
            const code = await loadItemFromAsyncStorage(KEY, {});
            setQrCode(() => code);
            setLoading(() => false);
        };
        loadQrCode();

    }, [])

    //This effect hook runs every time the code changes and persists it to async storage
    useEffect(() => {
        const storeQrCode = async (value) => {
            await storeItemInAsyncStorage(KEY, value);
        }

        storeQrCode(qrCode);

        return () => {
            storeQrCode(qrCode);
        } // this means the code will always be saved when the component unmounts.

    }, [qrCode]);

    //These three properties are available to your child components.
    const propertiesExposedToConsumers = { setQrCode, qrCode, loading };

    return (<QrCodeContext.Provider value={propertiesExposedToConsumers}>
        {children}
    </QrCodeContext.Provider>
    );
}



//asyncStrageWrapper.js.

export const storeItemInAsyncStorage = async (key, value) => {
    try {
        const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, jsonValue);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};

export const loadItemFromAsyncStorage = async (key, defaultValue = undefined) => {
    try {
        const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
        return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : defaultValue;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return defaultValue;
    }
};


//screenOne.js

const ScreenOne = () => {
    const { loading, qrCode } = useContext(QrCodeContext);

   //your render code here
}

//screenTwo.js
const ScreenTwo = () => {
    const { loading, setQrCode } = useContext(QrCodeContext);
    //your scanner code here.
}

//App.js
const App = () => (
    <QrCodeProvider>
       <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={"ScreenOne"}>
      <Stack.Screen name="ScreenOne" component={ScreenOne} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ScreenTwo" component={ScreenTwo} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    </QrCodeProvider >
)
```

Comment: I dont really have the time right now to look into this. But I will give you the bounty since it expires tomorrow